# How to catch IDL "message" with /informational flag

Tags: error-handling, idl-programming-language

I have a astronomy procedure that returns an error message, but it uses the /inf flag.  With this flag, none of the normal error flags are set.  So how would one catch such an error?  For example, I call the procedure, it prints out the informational error message, but how can I check if it outputted such a message?  I see it in the console, but how can the program check for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible. According to the [docs](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/MESSAGE.html), when the `INFORMATIONAL` keyword is set, `!error_state` is not changed.

> Set this keyword to issue informational text instead of an error. In this case, !ERROR_STATE is not set. The !QUIET system variable controls the printing of informational messages.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to get the last message posted to the terminal or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following (so long as nothing happened in between):

```
MESSAGE,/REISSUE_LAST
```

assuming you have IDL version greater than 6.0.  If not, then you can just go into the routine, modify it by defining a keyword that returns the message if it was printed to the screen, otherwise it returns nothing.